# character get garbled with utf8 JS ajax and spring - only in chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, google-chrome, utf-8

encoding non English chars with utf 8 on JS ajax and spring turn the chars into gibberish.

at first this issue happened on firefox as well, so I added UTF 8 to the HTTP request, to the page and to the jQuery ajax.

it didn't help.

Only when I change the request method from GET to POST the issue was solved, but then I tested on chrome and it still turn the chars to gibberish...

What is the reason it happen on chrome only?

How can I solve it?

NOTE: I cleared the cache, I used Ctrl+Shift+N window, I tested on different computers with new installation.

Comment: Please provide some code! Where is the text garbled - client, server, database, all? What server-side technology are you using?

Comment: Possibly the same as http://stackoverflow.com/q/17021425/136