# XHR request garbles encoding in Chrome, works fine in Safari

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, encoding

The following code POSTs "itâ€™s" in Chrome, but "it’s" in Safari.

```
invocation = new XMLHttpRequest()
invocation.open('POST', 'https://example.herokuapp.com/content/24/nl/123')
invocation.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8');
invocation.send('{"data":"it’s"}')
```

How do I convince Chrome to post using UTF-8?

Comment: Is the source file in utf-8 encoding?

Comment: The website has `<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">` in the header.

Comment: I solved this by using a workaround: `invocation.send('{"data":encodeURIComponent("it’s")}')`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set the response header

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

also on the `https://example.herokuapp.com/content/24/nl/123` target page, not just on the website (the request page). Also check if the encoding of any data source (including the target itself) is in UTF-8.

As far as I have tested, the garbled encoding comes only from the charset incompatibilities on the path

```
client encoding- client request- server encoding- server data- server response
```

**Note:** if your web server runs on PHP, you can use [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) for response header. If you can not set the header for some reason, use [iconv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) to convert the response from your charset to UTF-8.

Comment: That's not the problem - the http request that is sent to the server already mangles the characters. That's why it matters which browser is used.

Comment: @MichieldeMare The source file must also be stored in UTF-8, since you hard code `invocation.send('{"data":"it’s"}')` the **’** character to the request (the meta header is not enough). Are you sure the encoding matches on every part of the path I described in the answer? It works fine on my Chrome.

Comment: I run the Javascript from the Chrome console. I'm not sure how the encoding of the source page comes into play.

Comment: If the `’` character is hardcoded into the page, it uses the source file charset. If it doesn't match the response header charset, it is garbled. If you run it from console, it is up to the browser which charset is used: it seems that Chrome prefers the default OS charset, while Safari uses the source file charset.

Comment: The default charset of OSX 10.8 is not UTF-8?

Comment: Can you verify the source code charset? You need to go step by step and check the charset from client encoding to server response. I bet on some place there is something else than utf-8

Comment: If you open the console *right here on this SO page* and execute the snippet in the question, the error will still occur. Look at the Request Payload in the Network tab.